# applying for a 10 year UK visa

Tags: visas, uk

I've heard if I apply for a ten years UK visa it's necessary to have two five years visas already. Is this true or not? I had two six months & two two years visas before but just one five year visa.

Answer (score 4):

No such requirement is stated in the official guidance https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa or the Immigration Rules. To qualify, an applicant must meet the eligibility criteria for a visitor visa and demonstrate a credible reason for needing to visit the UK regularly over a longer period. Since travel history is taken into account for all visa decisions, anyone with a record of compliance with several UK visit visas may stand a better chance of success for a long-term visa than a first time applicant, but it would depend on the circumstances and the strength of the application.